# NIntegrate with highly oscillatory Bessel and hypergeometric integrands

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions, integral-transforms

I am trying to compute the following double integral

```
int2[n_] := NIntegrate[
n^2 * u * BesselJ[0, u]^n * r^2 * BesselJ[0, n*r*u],
{r, 0, 1}, {u, 0, Infinity}]
```

for various values of $n$.

For $n=2$, the integral can be computed exactly and equals $\frac{2}{\pi}$. For large $n$ the integral is asymptotically $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n}}$ (e.g., for $n=100$).

After exploring many methods, including those for oscillatory integrands, **I am unable to get a combination of method options that is able to give consistent results of 10-digit accuracy**.

The double integral can be put into a single integral by evaluating the $r$-part:

```
int1[n_] := NIntegrate[
u * (n^2/3) * BesselJ[0, u]^n * HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2}, {1, 5/2}, -(n*u)^2/4],
{u, 0, Infinity}]
```

My outcomes:

```
(* Should be *exactly* 0.6366197724 *)
int1[2] (* 0.6304358185 *)
int2[2] (* 0.6339084378 *)

(* Should be *approximately* 0.1253314137 *)
int1[50] (* 0.1254886991 *)
int2[50] (* 0.1254886992 *)
```

Any idea on how to compute precisely for all $n$ one of these integrals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the $u\to\infty$ asymptotic behavior of the integrand of your `int1`, specifically $J_0(u)\approx\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi u}}\cos\left(u-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$, it appears that the integrand goes to zero (approximately) for $u=\frac{3\pi}{4}+m\pi$ with $m\in\mathbb{N}_0$. This suggests splitting the integral into parts (intervals): $[0,\frac{3\pi}{4}]$, $[\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}]$, $[\frac{7\pi}{4},\frac{11\pi}{4}]$, $[\frac{11\pi}{4},\frac{15\pi}{4}]$, etc.

Further, the major contribution to the integral comes from the first interval: $u\in[0,\frac{3\pi}{4}]$.

Example:

```
intsplit[n_, {u1_, u2_}] := n^2/3 NIntegrate[
  u BesselJ[0, u]^n * HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2}, {1, 5/2}, -(n u/2)^2],
  {u, u1, u2}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]

intsplit[50, {0, 3π/4}]
(*    0.1254886990937379115286237327338243314274494412369262791291617704259250258960611335835624505156296499    *)

Table[intsplit[50, 3π/4 + {m, m + 1}*π], {m, 0, 4}] // N
(*    {-8.61042*10^-24, -1.04976*10^-30, -5.07022*10^-35,
       -3.61324*10^-38, -1.20061*10^-40}                     *)
```

You see that for $n=50$ we get at least the first 20 digits correctly by integrating only over $u\in[0,\frac{3\pi}{4}]$; the contributions from other intervals are negligible if you are aiming at $10^{-10}$ accuracy. For larger $n$ it will be even better.

```
intsplit[200, {0, 3π/4}]
(*    0.06268530928607771145004659153823798519393142799336461820358915795228778119416914850992024606679736243    *)
```

Comment: The splitting of the integrand was a very good catch! Thanks (+1)

Comment: @epsilone You're welcome. After a bit more thought it seems cleaner to integrate over the intervals between the zeros of $J_0(u)$: for the first (main) interval you can do `intsplit[50, {0, BesselJZero[0, 1]}]` etc. In practice this does not seem to make much difference, though, as the difference between $j_{0,1}=2.40483\ldots$ and the approximation $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ is only 2%.